# Trouble getting VersionData from ContentVersion through REST API - always returns null

Tags: rest-api, contentversion, php

I am trying to retrieve the binary file data from a `ContentVersion`. As i understand it, you get this from making a GET request to the value that is stored in `VersionData` on `ContentVersion`. For me it looks like `/services/data/v51.0/sobjects/ContentVersion/068Z0000000lxTxIAI/VersionData`

My application is a Laravel app and i am using a package called Forrest (https://github.com/omniphx/forrest) to make calls to the Salesforce REST API.

Currently, i am using this code:

```
$options = [
    'headers' => [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/octet-stream'
    ]
];

$res = Forrest::get('/services/data/v51.0/sobjects/ContentVersion/068Z0000000lxTxIAI/VersionData', [], $options);

dd($res);
```

The `dd()` is just for debugging. The `$res` is just always `null`. I don't believe it's getting the data. But it's also not failing. I know it's not failing because i can change the value and it fails with an actual exception.

Looking for any help. I'll literally try anything that allows me to retrieve the actual file data from the `ContentVersion` using PHP.

Comment: It may be due to the framework or could be down to the integrations contextual user not having the necessary permissions or sharing access. Have you tried enabling debug logs on Salesforce for your integration user?

Comment: Yea, i don't see anything in the logs at all for it and it looks like it has the right permissions. The package is, at its core, just making a simple get request with passing the auth and content type headers and things.

I can tell the package is working, at least, because if i add one character to the get url, it throws an actual exception, but the real url just returns null

Answer (score 0):

By default, this package will return the body of a response as either a deserialized JSON object or a SimpleXMLElement object. So, you will need to set default Forrest formatter to **none**:

```
$res = Forrest::sobjects('ContentVersion/068Z0000000lxTxIAI/VersionData', ['format' => 'none']);
```

And you can save the content to a file with:

```
Storage::put('file.jpg', $res);
```

Hope this helps!